# Can I lock the cells size in a datasheet view?

Tags: 2010, datasheet, formatting

I'm working on Sharepoint2010.
I have a datasheet which users can edit free. However I've noticed that everyone can change the size of the cells and even add other columns. How can I prevent any user to act on that?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have a Datasheet View on a list? The cell size **cannot** be modified on a datasheet view. I suspect you're talking about an Excel worksheet.

As for adding other columns, if you are in fact referring to a SharePoint list, then this can only be performed by a user with the the Manage Lists permission. By default, this permission is only available to the Edit, Design or Full Control permission level.

The simplest solution is to remove them from the Owners, Hierarchy Managers or Designers site groups (again assuming default groups and inherited permissions).

If the list's permission inheritance has been broken then you would need to revise this accordingly.